# Sending and Receiving bytes from socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, io

I want to make a Server, that lets a Client connect through a socket connection.

The thing I can't get done is that I can not find a method for sending a `byte`.

I only found articles and examples over sending Messages and Echoing, but that is not what I need, as the received bytes may not be visible.

Comment: I just typed "java socket connection tutorial" into Google and got about a dozen different tutorials that will lead you through the entire process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send a single `byte` via a connected [`Socket`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html), simply get it's [`OutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) and call [`.write()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28int%29) on that:

```
Socket s = ...;
byte b = 100;
s.getOutputStream().write(b);
```

For more in-depth information and examples, see the [Chapter on Sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) from the [Java Custom Networking Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/TOC.html).

Comment: I already gave you an example of writing a byte to a socket. You'll still have to open the socket (i.e. connect to a server or be a server and accept a connection), but for those there are plenty of examples/tutorials out there. I suggest [the official Java tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) ([this one is for specifically for you](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html))

Answer (score 1):

[Socket.getInputStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream%28%29) and [Socket.getOutputStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream%28%29) is what you are looking for. Also, take a look to [this example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html) for further info.

Regards.